How to get data size in sftp on Solaris10?
I have Solaris 10 server which serves as sftp servers. I want to know how much data is uploaded (written) and downloaded (read) on server on sftp protocol in 24 hours or more. How can I get this data ? In Linux I have sshd_config option with -l INFO -f AUTH but I am not able to figure this on Solaris. Probably, is it possible to get this data via snoop ?
Please suggest
Thanks

It is the same in Solaris, add this info in /etc/ssh/sshd_config  and restart the daemon. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/sftp-server-1m.html

It is true for Solaris 11, but no such options for Solaris 10

Solaris 10, an operating System from the year 2005. How about to get rid of that?

Getting rid of Solaris 10 is the focus and that is reason I am trying to collect this data to get the cost on new solution.
